# Google Chrome does not open

Tags: google-chrome

When I click on the Google Chrome icon from the launcher it does not open. I tried searching in the dash and clicking on its icon but it does not open at all.
I tried the terminal as well, like this:

```
$ google-chrome
```

and this is the output:

```
 (google-chrome:19866): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
 IA__gtk_settings_set_long_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS
 (settings)' failed

 (google-chrome:19866): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
 IA__gtk_settings_set_long_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS
 (settings)' failed

 (google-chrome:19866): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
 IA__gtk_settings_set_long_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS
 (settings)' failed

 (google-chrome:19866): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
 IA__gtk_settings_set_long_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS
 (settings)' failed

 (google-chrome:19866): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
 IA__gtk_settings_set_string_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS
 (settings)' failed

 (google-chrome:19866): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
 IA__gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)'
 failed

 (google-chrome:19866): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
 IA__gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)'
 failed

 (google-chrome:19866): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
 IA__gtk_icon_theme_prepend_search_path: assertion `GTK_IS_ICON_THEME
 (icon_theme)' failed

 (google-chrome:19866): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
 IA__gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)'
 failed

 (google-chrome:19866): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
 IA__gtk_icon_theme_prepend_search_path: assertion `GTK_IS_ICON_THEME
 (icon_theme)' failed

 (google-chrome:19866): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
 IA__gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)'
 failed

 (google-chrome:19866): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
 IA__gtk_icon_theme_prepend_search_path: assertion `GTK_IS_ICON_THEME
 (icon_theme)' failed

 (google-chrome:19866): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
 IA__gtk_settings_set_string_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS
 (settings)' failed

 (google-chrome:19866): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
 IA__gtk_settings_set_string_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS
 (settings)' failed

 (google-chrome:19866): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
 IA__gtk_settings_set_string_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS
 (settings)' failed
 [19866:19866:0426/060718:ERROR:process_singleton_linux.cc(239)]
 readlink(/home/omar/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed:
 Invalid argument
 [19866:19866:0426/060718:ERROR:process_singleton_linux.cc(239)]
 readlink(/home/omar/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed:
 Invalid argument
 [19866:19866:0426/060718:ERROR:process_singleton_linux.cc(263)] Failed
 to create /home/omar/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock: File exists
 [19866:19866:0426/060718:ERROR:process_singleton_linux.cc(239)]
 readlink(/home/omar/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed:
 Invalid argument
 [19866:19866:0426/060718:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1157)] Failed to
 create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that
 running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes
 rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now
 to avoid profile corruption.
```

Comment: Can you please provide the operating system name and version by editing your question?

Comment: Provide with your Ubuntu version you are using. Also, make sure no process of chrome is running (which looks like the problem based on what error you're seeing). For sanity check, before you click Chrome icon to launch it, run `killall chrome` in terminal and then start Chrome and see if it works.

Comment: i use ubuntu 12.10

Comment: i have forgotten to say that i tried reinstalling several times but no result

Comment: in addition gogle chrome works normaly on another ubuntu account but on my administrator acount it does not open

Comment: Funny, it doesn't even give the "Firefox is already running but is not responding" message when Chromium gets stuck.

Answer (score 6):

OVERVIEW

When google-chrome starts a session it creates some files under ~/.config/google-chrome and delete them when they are not in use anymore.

It is possible that some of these files remain there (because of some crash or upgrade or... whatever...). Then, when you try to run google-chrome it "thinks" that there is another active instance running and doesn't run the program (I'm assuming that you had verified in the list of processes that are no running instances of google-chrome).

SOLUTION

In this case, the basic solution is rename or delete these files, "SingletonLock", "SingletonCookie" and "SingletonSocket", and run google-chrome again. It will create these three files again and will run normally.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't find the `Singleton*` files discussed in other answers, another source of this error is exhaustion of disk space.

Try `df -h` to see how much space you have left on your partitions; if any are full, free up some space and try again.

Comment: In my case this helped. Actually I had problem with all the applications which I didn't notice. After deleting and moving some data the google chrome started normally and so did the rest of the applications.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that has worked is to remove

```
include "/usr/share/themes/oxygen-gtk/gtk-2.0/gtkrc"
```

if the line is in your `~/.gtkrc-2.0` file

Comment: I have faced the issue and completely removed this file. It did work for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is another reason for this issue:

Making a backup of all your files in your user folder, and keep that backup locally at say /local_backups/... (for later transfer, etc.) might cause chromium to behave the same way.

In this scenario there are not `Singleton*` files in folder, but it interferes with some files in the backup. (Don't ask me how...)

I resolved this issue by removing the backup.
Then it worked again.

Hope this helps anybody...

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the system disk (which has a journaling file system, etx4, so I'm a little surprised at that) was corrupted at shutdown, and fsck -a did not recover that.  That's actually a hard problem to find, so try `touch /test.txt` and if the file system is write locked, touch will tell you.  Running `fsck` to repair corruption in a file system is beyond the scope of this answer but the literature on `fsck` is vast and I recommend you read it either before you need it or else on another computer that is working.

TL,DR:

For you newbies, here is how to figure out some of the other questions that were posed in this thread, for future reference:

To get the operating system name and version number:
`$ uname -a`
To get the release or the version of the distribution:
`$ cat /etc/lsb-release`

Somebody suggested changing a directory to give everybody read/write/lookup access to a directory.  That should **not** be necessary, but if it is, it is.  First, see what the protection actually is and then change it.

```
$ ls -ld ~/.config/google-chrome/
drwx------. 30 jeffs jeffs 12288 Jan 11 16:09 google-chrome/
$ chmod 777 google-chrome/
```

At this point, test if that fixes the problem.  If not, then use `chmod` to set it back to the original value:

```
$ chmod 700 google-chrome/
```

I'm annoyed that the error message is so misleading, and I would consider that to be a bug in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Reason you got this error is,

you don't have permission to `/home/$USER/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock` this path.

Follow below steps it worked for me,

- go inside `/home/$USER/.config` folder (`cd /home/$USER/.config`)
- Give all the permission to google-chrome (`sudo chmod 777 google-chrome`)
- Run google chrome(`google-chrome`)

Hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

Run command

`rm -f ~/.config/chromium/SingletonLock`

It works for me

Comment: Not really an answer. Why run this command? What does it do? Add that info to the answer please.